# How to check if the System.in contains only numbers

Tags: java

Have a task to get N numbers from console, find the longest and the shortest ones and their length. The task is not difficult and works correctly, but I decided to make a check, if the console input corresponds the conditions of the task:

- Are there only Integer numbers.
- Are the exactly N numbers, not more/less.

I decided to write a boolean method isInputCorrect(), which would take the Scanner and check if the input is correct, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Hello, please enter " + n + " integer numbers:");
            while (!isInputCorrect(sc,n)){
                System.out.println("Wrong! Try again:");
                sc.next();
            }
        } while (!isInputCorrect(sc, 5));
        String scLine = sc.nextLine();
        String[] arr = scLine.split("\\s+");
        String maxLengthNum = arr[0];
        String minLengthNum = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
            if (maxLengthNum.length() < arr[i].length()){
                maxLengthNum = arr[i];
            }
            if (minLengthNum.length() > arr[i].length()){
                minLengthNum = arr[i];
            }
        }
        String equalMaxNum = "";
        String equalMinNum = "";
        int countMax = 0;
        int countMin = 0;
        for (String s : arr){
            if (maxLengthNum.length() == s.length()){
                countMax += 1;
                equalMaxNum += s + " ";
            }
            if (minLengthNum.length() == s.length()){
                countMin += 1;
                equalMinNum += s + " ";
            }
        }
        if (countMax > 1){
            System.out.println("The longest numbers are: " + equalMaxNum + " Their length is: " + maxLengthNum.length());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The longest number is: " + maxLengthNum + " Its length is: " + maxLengthNum.length());
        }
        if (countMin > 1){
            System.out.println("The shortest numbers are: " + equalMinNum + " Their length is: " + minLengthNum.length());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The shortest number is: " + minLengthNum + " Its length is: " + minLengthNum.length());
        }
    }
    public static boolean isInputCorrect(Scanner sc, int n){
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if (sc.hasNextInt()){
                sc.next();
            }else {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

**EDIT**
This code still doesn't work. I realize, that the problem is in isDigit(). And exactly in regular conditions in last if statement. It is something like this:

```
public static boolean isDigit (String input, int n){
    String[] arr = input.split("\\s+");
    boolean flag = false;
    if (arr.length != n){
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        for (String s : arr) {
            if (s.startsWith("-")) {
                if (s.substring(1).matches("[0-9]*")) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            } else if (s.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                flag = true;
            } else {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

This method takes the console input as a string, then it checks, how many numbers(strings) does it contain, are there any negative numbers and so on. But it can be applied only for substrings(words without whitespace). In my case it can be applied to arr[i].

So I modified it to split String into array[] and tried to check every single element. I've got:

```
public static boolean isDigit (String input, int n){
    String[] arr = input.split("\\s+");
    boolean flag = false;
    if (arr.length != n){
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        for (String s : arr) {
            if (s.startsWith("-")) {
                if (s.substring(1).matches("[0-9]*")) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            } else if (s.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                flag = true;
            } else {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

but it returnes true even when input is:
1 3213 w 15 3
I can't understand, what is the problem? The full code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n = 5;
            boolean validInput = false;
            String input;
            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter " + n + " integer numbers:");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                input = sc.nextLine();
                if (isDigit(input, n)) {
                    validInput = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Wrong input! Try again: ");
                }
            }
            while (!validInput);
    
            String[] arr = input.split("\\s+");
    
            String maxLengthNum = arr[0];
            String minLengthNum = arr[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
                if (maxLengthNum.length() < arr[i].length()){
                    maxLengthNum = arr[i];
                }
                if (minLengthNum.length() > arr[i].length()){
                    minLengthNum = arr[i];
                }
            }
    
            String equalMaxNum = "";
            String equalMinNum = "";
    
            int countMax = 0;
            int countMin = 0;
    
            for (String s : arr){
                if (maxLengthNum.length() == s.length()){
                    countMax += 1;
                    equalMaxNum += s + " ";
                }
                if (minLengthNum.length() == s.length()){
                    countMin += 1;
                    equalMinNum += s + " ";
                }
            }
            if (countMax > 1){
                System.out.println("The longest numbers are: " + equalMaxNum + " Their length is: " + maxLengthNum.length());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The longest number is: " + maxLengthNum + " Its length is: " + maxLengthNum.length());
            }
            if (countMin > 1){
                System.out.println("The shortest numbers are: " + equalMinNum + " Their length is: " + minLengthNum.length());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The shortest number is: " + minLengthNum + " Its length is: " + minLengthNum.length());
            }
        }
    
        public static boolean isDigit (String input, int n){
        String[] arr = input.split("\\s+");
        boolean flag = false;
        if (arr.length != n){
            flag = false;
        }
        else {
            for (String s : arr) {
                if (s.startsWith("-")) {
                    if (s.substring(1).matches("[0-9]*")) {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                } else if (s.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                    flag = true;
                } else {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

**SOLVED**

**Thanks to everybody, your help was really usefull. I finally found the problem**
It was in isDigit() method. It was checking out every element of array, and switched a flag according to the last result. I wrote "break" to stop the further checking if there was at least one false flag in loop.

```
public static boolean isDigit (String input, int n){
        String[] arr = input.split("\\s+");
        boolean flag = false;
        if (arr.length != n){
            flag = false;
        }
        else{
            for (String s: arr){
                if (s.startsWith("-")) {
                    if (s.substring(1).matches("[0-9]*")){
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (s.matches("[0-9]*")){
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: Hi There. What do you mean by `doesn't work correctly`. What is the expectation and what is happening ?

Comment: Do you realize that your `isInputCorrect` is going to read and discard `n` integers.  Once they are discarded, you won't be able to get them back.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now I realize, that I can't use scanner for this purpose.

Comment: `while (!validInput);` is an infinite loop when validInput is false. You don't have a loop body.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was in another place.

Answer (score 0):

You may use regular expressions to verify that the input contains only integer numbers:

```java
int n = 5;
// ... your current code

String scLine = sc.nextLine();
if (!scLine.matches("\\d+(?:\\s+\\d+)*")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("input contained non-integers");
}

String[] arr = scLine.split("\\s+");
if (arr.length != n) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("found " + arr.length + " number inputs but expected " + n + ".");
}
```

Comment: Uff, it is hard for me to understand the first if statement yet, I've just started tu study Java, sorry(. The second part is clear.

Comment: Notice that your regex returns false on the string "-1" . And I think that you can set the number of expected tokens in the regex, needing just one line to declare the input invalid.

Comment: @RubioRic Where do you see the OP allowing for negative numbers?  Wouldn't it be a better user experience to give different exceptions for a problem with types versus number of elements?

Comment: I've not checked OP's code but the question asserts that "Are there only Integer numbers".  Integers include negative numbers. I'm not so sure about the exact number of error messages, that was just a suggestion, but less code written, less code to fix in the future. :-)

Comment: Ok, I tried it, and it works, but I need to give a user ability to reenter the integers without finishing the programe. How can I catch an Exception and return to the start?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if input string has only numbers as below

```
public  boolean isDigit(String input) {

        if (input == null || input.length() < 0)
            return false;
        input = input.trim();
        if ("".equals(input))
            return false;
        if (input.startsWith("-")) {
            return input.substring(1).matches("[0-9]*");
        } else {
            return input.matches("[0-9]*");
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

allowing user to re-enter untill valid number is entered

```
boolean validInput = false;
do
{
  System.out.println("Enter the number ");
   // get user input
   String input  sc.nextLine();
  if(isDigit(input))
    validInput  = true;
  else
    System.out.println("Enter valid Number");
}
while (!validInput );
```

Comment: Tried to apply such method in my code, it works too and it is more understandable for me. But how should I use it in main? Using do..while or recursion instead?

Comment: you call `isDigit` from main by changing the method as static,  calling it in `for` loop like  `for (String s : arr){ isDigit(s) }`

Comment: in your code call  `isDigit` instead of  `isInputCorrect`

Comment: Thats right, but a dont understand how to give a user an opportunity to reenter nums in console if isDigit is false) Only with recursive method, am I right?

Comment: updated answer with code to allow user to re-enter untill its valid input